# Yii multiselect widget

Tags: yii-extensions

I have the following code that produces a jquery ech multiselect menu widget in Yii. (Eric Hynds multiselect).

I have downloaded the extension and unzipped in extensions folder
and my folder structure is My_lokal_Yii/protected/extensions/EchMultiSelect/EchMultiSelect

this is my view file code..

```
<?php $this->widget('ext.EchMultiselect.EchMultiselect', array(
'model' => $model,
'dropDownAttribute' => 'color',     
'data' => $list,
'dropDownHtmlOptions'=> array(
    'style'=>'width:378px;',
),
```

));?>

and in config/main.php i have imported the extension as

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
            'application.extensions.EchMultiselect.*'
),
```

But i am getting error that "Alias "ext.EchMultiselect.EchMultiselect" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable."

I have given all the permissions for the EchMultiselect file.

Please help me in this.. Thank you.. I tried a lot but did't get the exact result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my folder structure is 
    My_lokal_Yii/protected/extensions/EchMultiSelect/EchMultiSelect

but in your config/main.php, there is:

```
... 'application.extensions.EchMultiselect.*'

------------------------------------^
```

It lacks the capital letter "s" and therefore the exact path/naming to/of your extension, I had the same "problem" with it ;-) , maybe it helps...
Greetings